Powershell Winforms GUI - in CheckedListBox, prevent user from unchecking all checkboxes and retain "only 1 checkbox at any one time" in event handler
I'm very new to powershell winforms, apologies if this is a basic question...
Basically the title... i have a crappy GUI form (and yes i know i should probably use a radial button, please don't suggest changing that).
I want the user to ONLY be able to check a single checkbox at any one point in time, and i never want them to be able to uncheck all checkboxes.. at the moment if they click on Option 1, when it is already checked, it will successfully allow them to uncheck Option 1 and then nothing is checked and the user has managed to f#$^ themselves (as they always seem to manage to find a way to do).
Please help :(
My understanding is i need to modify the $checkListBox.add_ItemCheck event handler, but i can't wrap my brain around how i would do that, whilst retaining the existing behaviour.
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300, 200)

$checkListBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox
$checkListBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 10)
$checkListBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 150)

# Add items to the checkListBox
$checkListBox.Items.Add("Option 1") | Out-Null
$checkListBox.Items.Add("Option 2") | Out-Null
$checkListBox.Items.Add("Option 3") | Out-Null
$checkListBox.SelectionMode = 'One'
$checkListBox.CheckOnClick = $true
$checkListBox.SetItemChecked(0, $true) # set the first item by default.

# Add ItemCheck event handler
$checkListBox.add_ItemCheck({
    param($sender, $e)
    foreach ($index in $checkListBox.CheckedIndices) {
        if ($index -ne $e.Index) {
            $checkListBox.SetItemChecked($index, $false)
        }
    }
})

$form.Controls.Add($checkListBox)

$form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null


Tried this below...and it seems to work :) .. Not entirely sure if it is the correct/safe way of doing things however:
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300, 200)

$checkListBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox
$checkListBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 10)
$checkListBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 150)
("Option 1","Option 2","Option 3") | % {$checkListBox.Items.Add("$_") | Out-Null}
$checkListBox.SelectionMode = 'One'
$checkListBox.CheckOnClick = $true
$checkListBox.SetItemChecked(0, $true) # set the first item by default.

$handlingEvent = $false

$checkListBox.add_ItemCheck({
    param($sender, $e)
    if ($handlingEvent) { return }
    $handlingEvent = $true
    try {
        $currentCheckedState = [System.Windows.Forms.CheckState]::Unchecked
        $newCheckedState = [System.Windows.Forms.CheckState]::Unchecked
        if ($e.CurrentValue -eq 1) { $currentCheckedState = [System.Windows.Forms.CheckState]::Checked }
        if ($e.NewValue -eq 1) { $newCheckedState = [System.Windows.Forms.CheckState]::Checked }
        if ($currentCheckedState -eq [System.Windows.Forms.CheckState]::Checked -and $newCheckedState -eq [System.Windows.Forms.CheckState]::Unchecked) { $e.NewValue = [System.Windows.Forms.CheckState]::Checked }
        $checkListBox.CheckedIndices | ForEach-Object { if ($_ -ne $e.Index) { $checkListBox.SetItemChecked($_, $false) } }
    } finally { $handlingEvent = $false }
})

$form.Controls.Add($checkListBox)

# Show the form, but since we only seem to get "cancel" in the resultant object, no point keeping it. we only care what checkbox they selected..
$form.ShowDialog() | out-null

# Output the result
$DialogOut = $checkListBox.CheckedItems
Write-host "User Selected: $DialogOut"


Before your foreach you need to add something like if( ($e.CurrentValue -eq “Checked”) -and ($e.NewValue -eq “Unchecked) ) { $e.NewValue -eq “Checked” } - this will prevent the user from unchecking boxes. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.itemcheckeventargs?view=windowsdesktop-8.0#properties. (You might need to tweak it to get Powershell to cast the CheckedState enum names to the correct type, and it mighf end up triggering cascading events so may so may need to check for re-entrance - I can’t test right now sh shooting from the hip a bit :-)

This is great, thank you so much for your help mclayton! Not going to lie i don't know what the cascading events means.. so i don't know if what ChatGPT has created here is absolute garbage (which sadly is a frequent occurance when i ask it questions) or not.. but it seems to have come through with the good this time ... it's too long to post as a reply apparently...i have pasted it above in the post body.

re "cascading events" I meant that changing the CheckedState of an item inside the ItemCheck event handler could potentially trigger the event handler again, and then you'd change the CheckedState again, triggering the event handler, etc ad infinitum (or until you got a Stack Overflow).  It sounds like that doesn't happen though, so you're all good...

Also, consider adding your update as an answer to your own question and marking it as the answer to the question - it'll show as "answered" in the search results for future readers then (I'm not sure how much rep you need to do that, but I've just given you a +1 to bump your current score :-))

This seems to have sorted it, thanks @mclayton!
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300, 200)

$checkListBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox
$checkListBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 10)
$checkListBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 150)
("Option 1","Option 2","Option 3") | % {$checkListBox.Items.Add("$_") | Out-Null}
$checkListBox.SelectionMode = 'One'
$checkListBox.CheckOnClick = $true
$checkListBox.SetItemChecked(0, $true) # set the first item by default.

$handlingEvent = $false

$checkListBox.add_ItemCheck({
    param($sender, $e)
    if ($handlingEvent) { return }
    $handlingEvent = $true
    try {
        $currentCheckedState = [System.Windows.Forms.CheckState]::Unchecked
        $newCheckedState = [System.Windows.Forms.CheckState]::Unchecked
        if ($e.CurrentValue -eq 1) { $currentCheckedState = [System.Windows.Forms.CheckState]::Checked }
        if ($e.NewValue -eq 1) { $newCheckedState = [System.Windows.Forms.CheckState]::Checked }
        if ($currentCheckedState -eq [System.Windows.Forms.CheckState]::Checked -and $newCheckedState -eq [System.Windows.Forms.CheckState]::Unchecked) { $e.NewValue = [System.Windows.Forms.CheckState]::Checked }
        $checkListBox.CheckedIndices | ForEach-Object { if ($_ -ne $e.Index) { $checkListBox.SetItemChecked($_, $false) } }
    } finally { $handlingEvent = $false }
})

$form.Controls.Add($checkListBox)

# Show the form, but since we only seem to get "cancel" in the resultant object, no point keeping it. we only care what checkbox they selected..
$form.ShowDialog() | out-null

# Output the result
$DialogOut = $checkListBox.CheckedItems
Write-host "User Selected: $DialogOut"

